# Are homozygous carriers of the CCR5-Δ32 allele fully immune to all known strains of HIV?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, virology, hiv

Or is there documented evidence of even one homozygous carrier contracting HIV and staying infected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no.
Some HIV strains are X4-tropic and not R5 tropic. That means that the virus uses the CXCR4 coreceptor and not the CCR5 coreceptor for entry into the CD4-positive cell.